# how to use do and while loop in haskell

Tags: loops, haskell, while-loop, do-loops, do-notation

I tried to use an addition and print every step, but it doesn't work, can someone help me out please?

```
addition x = x+1
acc_addition xs = do print xs
                     let result = addition xs
                         if result == 5
                            then return ()
                            else do
                                 print result
                                 addition result
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Note that Haskell doesn't have loops; it has recursion.

Comment: sorry i'm not native speaker, what I wanted to do is like this : acc_addition 1; then it shows 1;2; 3;4;5

Comment: `do` is not a do-while loop, it is something completely different. If you're a Haskell beginner, which you appear to be, I'd recommend reading [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) first.

Comment: I think the phrasing "do and while loop" was just unfortunate, and that the intended meaning was "How do I write this while-loop equivalent using 'do'?", i.e. "How do I make this tail recursive function monadic?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty close, you just have to call `acc_addition` instead of `addition` as the last step. Syntactically, you also need an `in` for your `let` statement:

```
addition x = x+1
acc_addition xs = do print xs
                     let result = addition xs in
                         if result == 5
                            then return ()
                            else do
                                 print result
                                 acc_addition result
```

When run via `ghci`:

```
*Main> acc_addition 1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
```

The reason why it prints twice is of course that you have two print statements.

Comment: @AndyTsao: Here are [some minor style suggestions](https://gist.github.com/evincarofautumn/a9a85543ec788f8d5a3fa20e8b9003d5) as well.

Comment: @AndyTsao A few minor points: the above style is usually avoided in Haskell, when it is possible to do so. We do not like to mix pure computation and IO further than needed. In this specific case, one could instead write a pure function generating the list `[1,2,2,3,3,4,4]` (using recursion), and then finally print that list (`for_ myList print`). Also, it is usually recommended to start writing any top-level function from its type, so to allow GHC to produce better error messages.

Comment: instead of adding the `in` you could also un-indent the `if` to start at exactly the same indentation as `let` above it.